# How do I limit my react-redux app to only make API request when required data is not available?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Ok, so I have a products page in which I'm making request to an API to get the data. Now, if I click on  specific product, another page opens up with the said product details. If I go back to the products page, it's making a request again to the API even while my redux dev tools show that I have the products in my redux state so I don't need to make another API request. So, what I want to do is not to make an API request if I have the products in my state.

This is how the products page code looks like:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const productList = useSelector(state => state.productList);
  const { loading, error, products } = productList;

  useEffect(() => {
    if(products.len===0 || products.len===undefined)
      dispatch(listProducts());
  }, [])
```

The `listProducts()` looks like this:

```
export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST })
    
    const { data } = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/products");

    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
      payload: data
    })

  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
      payload: error.response && error.response.data.error ? error.response.data.error : error.message
    })
  }
}
```

And, here's the relevant reducer:

```
export const productListReducer = (state = { products: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
        return { loading: true, products:[] }
    case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, products: action.payload }
    case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: in listProducts there is second argument available async (dispatch, state), where you can check if there is data in state

Comment: I just tried that.. but it's still firing off the actions and making requests.

Comment: Can you console.log state at listProducts? And also have in mind if you do it like this the list will not update if product changes or gets removed at the time you are using it from the state

Comment: yeah I logged it and it did show 6 items in the product array and I included the conditional in listProducts to just return the state if the array has more than 0 items but I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: It is because you did not put the check on the request itself here const { data } = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/products"); , do check on this. And also return the products from state

Comment: I don't get what you mean by 'checking on the request itself'

Comment: I think this is a simple typo!  Try replacing products.len in your conditional with products.length.

Comment: @Linda Paiste yes you're right. The typo fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List Products

```
   export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch, state) => {
  
   try {
   dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST })
   const { data } = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/products");

   dispatch({
    type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
    payload: data
   })

} catch (error) {
  dispatch({
    type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
    payload: error.response && error.response.data.error ? error.response.data.error : error.message
  })
  }
}
```

Products page

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const productList = useSelector(state => state.productList);
const { loading, error, products } = productList;

useEffect(() => {
  if(products.length===0)
    dispatch(listProducts());
}, [])
```

Comment: `PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST` is still firing off.

Comment: oh it works now. I just had to change products.len to products.length as suggested by Linda and this works now. Thanks.

Comment: I just updated the code and also didn't see that typo